# Set theory - Can someone explain sequence operator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading up on set theory and relation and I need help understanding this:
Two sequences of the same element type can be composed to form a single sequence in
such a way that the order of each sequence is maintained, and the elements of one sequence follow the elements of the other. The composition operator, representing concatenation,
is defined as

[image: sequence operator]

Can someone explain this in simple English. I don't understand the notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to call the map $c$, not whatever that symbol is.

The first two lines mean $c$ is a function which takes a pair of sequences $s = (s_1, \dotsc, s_n)$ and $t = (t_1, \dotsc, t_m)$, where $n = \#s$ and $m = \#t$ are the lengths, and outputs a new sequence $c(s, t)$. The next lines tell us the elements of the sequence $c(s, t)$. This suffices as a definition because sequences are determined by their elements. If $1 \le i \le n$, the $i$th element of $c(s,t)$ is $s_i$. Any number bigger than $n$ can be written as $i + n$ for some $i$, so if $1\le i \le m$, the $(i+n)$th element of $c(s,t)$ is $t_i$. Personally, I would write this part as "if $n < i \le n + m$, the $i$th element of $c(s,t)$ is $t_{n-i}$".

What really is going on here is best illustrated by an example: $c((s_1, s_2, s_3), (t_1, t_2)) = (s_1, s_2, s_3, t_1, t_2)$.

All the remark about additivity is saying is that if you stick two sequences together, the length of the result is the sum of the length of the parts.